# How to remove partial strings which match in the same column in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, string-matching

I have a data frame with columns as below:

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Hello guys
 D    Originally posted by A Hi, how are you? I am doing good
 E    Whats going on ?
 F    Originally posted by B I am doing good Welcome
```

I want to remove text which partially matches the rows in column df_text. For example in the above code user D replied to user A, that's why it has "originally posted by .." string. I need to keep the actual text of user D and get rid of all those strings which has "originally posted" along with the associated user and text.

I do not understand how to go about it . I tried the following code:

```
df_text[!df_text %in% grep(paste0(df_text, collapse = "|"), df_text, value = T)]
```

What I expect to get is:

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Hello guys
 D    I am doing good
 E    Whats going on ?
 F    Welcome
```

Is it possible to get the above results ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Comment: I want to get rid of the text "originally posted by ..." till the matching text associated with the previous row and the user column.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually test for a text that has already been written by using a [Backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), and then clear the whole match **before** what you need to remove, see this regex:

```regex
(?:[A-Z] {4})?(.+?$)\n[\s\S]*?\KOriginally posted by [A-Z] \1
```

### Explanation

#### Search for

- `(?:[A-Z] {4})?` - Matches the first part of the string ( `A`    ).
- `(.+?$)` - The capturing group that will be referenced as `\1`, this is the text `A` sent.
- `\n[\s\S]*?` - Next line, and keep the selection until it finds the `Originally po...`.
- `\K` - Clears the whole selection, so when you `.replace()` you won't delete important stuff.

#### Match

- `Originally posted by [A-Z]` - The text that makes reference to `A`'s message.
- `\1` - The text `A` sent, so you can erase it all from `B`'s message.
- - And of course, a space to be removed (this way the final text wont be messed up).

### Algorithm

I have no idea how to translate this algorithm to R, but here it is anyways:

```js
    var rgx = /(?:[A-Z] {4})?(.+?$)\n[\s\S]*?\KOriginally posted by [A-Z] \1 /;
    while (str.match(rgx))
        str = str.replace(rgx, "");
```

#### Notes:

- Remember to use `perl=TRUE`
- This regex requires a loop, as it cannot match "nested strings" (see [Regex101's example](https://regex101.com/r/UJqIRT/1))
- Note there is a space at the end of the expression

---

## Example

### Text

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Heuwi
 D    Originally posted by C Heuwi Hellou
 E    Hello guys
 F    Originally posted by A Hi, how are you ? I am doing good
 G    Whats going on ?
 H    Test2
 I    Originally posted by B I am doing good Welcome
 J    Originally posted by C Test2 Hellou
```

### First run

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Heuwi
 D    Originally posted by C Heuwi Hellou
 E    Hello guys
 F    I am doing good
 G    Whats going on ?
 H    Test2
 I    Welcome
 J    Originally posted by C Test2 Hellou
```

### Last run

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Heuwi
 D    Hellou
 E    Hello guys
 F    I am doing good
 G    Whats going on ?
 H    Test2
 I    Welcome
 J    Hellou
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this code :  `gsub("/(?:[A-Z] {4})?(.+?$)\n[\s\S]*?\KOriginally Posted by [A-Z] \1 /", "",df_text)` , it gives methe following error `(Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/(?:[A-Z] {4})?(.+?$)\n[\S")`

Comment: As [this](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#cb11-3) website suggests, you probably have to escape the backslashes in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` to replace text/pattern with nothing `""` for example:

`df$df_text <- gsub("Originally posted by ","",df$df_text)`

where `df` is your dataframe with columns `user`, `df_text`

for more you can go with for cycle

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df){

  df$df_text[i] <- gsub(paste0("Originally posted by ",
                               df$df_text[i-1]),"",df$df_text[i])

}
```

this should give you wanted result, but it is quite slow

Comment: That doesnt work because it is not considering the previous reference row. Is there a way to partially match text within the same column and to get rid of "Originally posted by" along with the previous user and the text ?

Comment: It gives me empty (NULL) result unfortunately.

Comment: can you try posting fragment of your data by `dput()` so i can try it on your actual data